Can you espalier peach, plum and cherry trees?
I read that espaliers are usually made with apples and pears. Why not cherries, plums and peaches?
I'm thinking of making a Belgian fence with 6 different kinds of trees (apple, pear, plum, peach, cherry, nectarine). Will this work?

Note: it depends also on varieties (and rootstock), to have moderate sized plants.

Yes, you can espalier stone fruit trees, although apparently the process is a little different to apples and pears because stone fruit don't produce fruit on spurs. (IE stone fruit need to be espaliered in a fan shape)
https://www.waimeanurseries.co.nz/home-gardeners/guides/how-to-guides/how-to-espalier-fruit-trees/
and
https://bigjims.co.nz/growing-guides/stone-fruit back this up.

Thanks so much for your answer! It's very helpful. I see I can't make a Belgian fence with stone fruit. I'll look at fan-shaped espaliers. Thanks!
